# Compare two CSV files and create a new CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files that each have two columns, `id` and `name`. I want to compare both files by their `name` columns; if the values match, then create a new CSV file with the `id` values from both files.

1.csv:

```
id, name  
1, sofia  
2, Maria  
3, sofia
4, Laura
```

2.csv:

```
id, name
1, sofia
2, Laura
```

My code:

```
import csv

with open('1.csv') as companies, open('2.csv') as tags:
    companies = companies.readlines()
    tags = tags.readlines()

with open('CompanieTags.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in companies:
        if line[1] != tags[1]:
            line2 = companies[1]
                outFile.write(line[0] and linea2)
```

Other code with Dict's

```
import csv

with open('1.csv') as companies, open('2.csv') as tags:
    reader = csv.DictReader(companies)
    check = csv.DictReader(tags)

with open('CompanieTags.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for x in check:

        SaveTag = x['name']

        for y in reader:
            if SaveTag in y['name'] :
                outFile.write(y['id'], x['id'])
```

Expected result:

```
id, name
1, 1
3, 1
4, 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is it you're trying to fix? If the output is not what you expect, please list what you're getting and how it differs from what you want. If you're getting an error, list the error message. Presenting a specific problem will help us answer your question more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another version of the answer:
 - not using itertools
 - loading the csv files
 - using the csv files in the post

```
import csv

NAME = 1
ID = 0


def load_csv(file_name):
    res = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
            if idx > 0:
                res.append(row)
    return res


lst1 = load_csv('1.csv')
lst2 = load_csv('2.csv')

result = []
for x in lst1:
    for y in lst2:
        if x[NAME] == y[NAME]:
            result.append((x[ID], y[ID]))
print(result)
```

output

```
[('1', '1'), ('3', '1'), ('4', '2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

(I skip loading the data from files to list of tuples - I assume you can do it)

```
import csv
from itertools import cycle

lst1 = [(1, 'Jack'), (4, 'Ben'), (5, 'Sofi')]
lst2 = [(12, 'Jack'), (4, 'Jack'), (15, 'Jack')]

names1 = {x[1] for x in lst1}
names2 = {x[1] for x in lst2}
common = names1.intersection(names2)

common_in_1 = [x[0] for x in lst1 if x[1] in common]
common_in_2 = [x[0] for x in lst2 if x[1] in common]

result = zip(common_in_1, cycle(common_in_2)) if len(common_in_1) > len(common_in_2) else zip(cycle(common_in_1),
                                                                                              common_in_2)

print(list(result))

# write to output file
with open('out.csv', mode='w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(result)
```

output

```
[(1, 12), (1, 4), (1, 15)]
```

Comment: OP specifically asked how to create a CSV file as the program's output.

Comment: @Das_Geek I agree with your point but I thought the main challenge here is to find the common entries in both input files. I believe writing to a new csv will be trivial for the OP

Comment: @Das_Geek Anyway. I have added the code that writes the common entries to a new csv file

Comment: Have a problem, if there were 3 names in the second list
example: 
lst2 = [(12, 'Jack'), (4, 'Jack'), (15, 'Jack')] 
the result is (1, 12)


I would like it to be: (1, 12) (1,4) (1,15)

Comment: Is it possible (on your side)  to have 'Jack' many times in one list?

Comment: @Jlarteaga I have modified the code to support "multi jack" in one list

Comment: Yes, if you look at the result of my example Sofia appears twice in the first list.

In the result shows both

Comment: @Jlarteaga I think the updated code will work for you. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: @balderman when importing the csv and replacing it in list1 and list2 the result is different
[('i', 'i'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', 'i'), ('4', '1') , ('5', '2')]
[('i', 'i'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', 'i'), ('4', '1') , ('5', '2')]

Comment: share your updated code and the csv's (2 input files). BTW - did the "multi jack" worked for you?

Comment: The code that you passed me if it worked, but when I incorporate the CSV files it does not work well

Comment: @Jlarteaga I will able to assist if you will share the 2 csv's (or the 2 lists)

Comment: **1.csv**  `id,name
1,Sofia
2,Sofia srl
3,Sofia srl
4,Sofia
5,Laura` and **2.csv** `id,name
1,Sofia
2,Laura`

Comment: @Jlarteaga I have checked the code with your latest input. `lst1 = [(2, 'Sofia'), (3, 'Sofia srl'), (4, 'Sofia srl'), (2, 'Laura')]
lst2 = [(1, 'Sofia'), (5, 'Laura')]` The output is `[(2, 1), (5, 2)]` which is the correct output. I think you have an issue with the way you load the data from csv.

Comment: I think the problem is in the import. If I import the CSV file as an array the result is: 1, Jack 2, Ben 3, Laura || if I import it as a dict {1: 'Jack' 2: 'Ben' 3: 'Laura'}. In your example (1, 'Jack'), (4, 'Ben'), (5, 'Sofi')

If you could do it by importing the files, you would help me a lot

Comment: @Jlarteaga I have submitted another answer. This time I load the csv files you have posted. I think it works well.